# check when a txt file was last written to in PHP

Tags: php, caching, text, time

I'm writing to a .txt file using php like this:

```
$File = "example.txt"; 
$h = fopen($File, 'w');
$Data = "some info"; 
fwrite($h, $Data); 
fclose($h);
```

But I only want it to write to that file if it's been more than 5 minutes since the last time I wrote to it (essentially I'm creating a 5 minute cache).

Is there any way to check when was the last time I wrote to it and create some kind of conditional statement that triggers the code above?

Comment: Look into the `filemtime` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use filemtime() check [manual](http://pk1.php.net/filemtime) here.

```
  $filename = 'somefile.txt';
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        echo "$filename was last modified: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filename));
    }
```